# Don't play sound

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, audio

I converted my project to ARC. Xcode changed this line in code from example

```
soundFileURLRef = (CFURLRef) [tapSound retain];
```

to

```
soundFileURLRef = (__bridge CFURLRef) tapSound;
```

but no sound plays. What's wrong?

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender {
        // Create the URL for the source audio file. The URLForResource:withExtension: method is new in iOS 4.0
        NSURL *tapSound = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"abide" withExtension: @"aif"];

        CFURLRef        soundFileURLRef;
        SystemSoundID   soundFileObject;

        // Store the URL as a CFURLRef instance
        soundFileURLRef = (__bridge CFURLRef) tapSound; // I think this line is wrong

        // Create a system sound object representing the sound file.
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (

                                          soundFileURLRef,
                                          &soundFileObject
                                          );

        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundFileObject);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Logically, your code looks completely fine. I suspect that you have not actually bundled `abide.aif` with your application, or you have accidentally typed the name wrong (could the extension be `aiff`?). You can verify this by putting a breakpoint after the `[NSBundle URLForResource:withExtension:]` call, and checking the contents of `tapSound`.

Be sure that you have actually included it for your target in the "copy bundle resources":

[image]

In addition, you should be aware that calls to `AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID` should be balanced with a `AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID` call. You are allocating memory needlessly here, and ARC will not take care of this for you.

The ideal way to do this would be to do all the work to create a `SystemSoundID` in your `awakeFromNib` or `viewDidLoad` method, store it as an ivar, and only call `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` in your button tap method. In your dealloc method, you should call `AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID`.

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I believe you meant to say "only call `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound()` in your button tap method". Nice write-up though.

Comment: @NJones: Whoops! Thanks for spotting that.