# eschewing retain sysSound

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, retain

[Docs suggest the following](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SysSound/Listings/Classes_SysSoundViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008018-Classes_SysSoundViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6) but **retain** is not allowed when using ARC. What is a workaround, please?

```
// Create the URL for the source audio file. The URLForResource:withExtension: method is
    //    new in iOS 4.0.
    NSURL *tapSound   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"tap"
                                                withExtension: @"aif"];

    // Store the URL as a CFURLRef instance
    self.soundFileURLRef = (CFURLRef) [tapSound retain];
```

Comment: `self.soundFileURLRef = (__bridge_retained CFURLRef) tapSound;`
"By using __bridge_retained, we can tell ARC to transfer ownership out of the system and into our hands. Since ownership is transferred, we're now responsible for releasing the object when done with it, just like with any other CF code..."(http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-30-automatic-reference-counting.html)

Comment: Thanks. The good news is that no error was thrown with your suggestion, but I am not hearing the tapSound. And I have another question. Do I have to  undo the sound with `self.soundFileURLRef = nil;` in `viewDidUnload`? Is there some way to be sure that the resource tap.aif was found?

Comment: [I got all questions answered at ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600424/dont-play-sound). I had not added the sound file from off the web into my NSBundle. That link also shows how to be surer the resource was working. Thanks.